# In sales order grid shipping addess in i getting error can i know how solve this error magento 2?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-email, order-grid

like this in shipping address First Name

{{if this.getTemplateFilter().filter(dummy)}}{{/if}}

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

- Open your Magento admin panel and go to "Stores" > "Configuration".
- In the left sidebar, under "Sales," click on "Shipping Settings" and then select "Shipping Methods."
- Locate the shipping method you are using and click on it to expand the configuration options.
- Look for the "Fields" or "Address Fields" section, which allows you to customize the fields displayed in the shipping address form.
- Find the "First Name" field and check if there are any conditions or filters applied to it. Remove or modify any filters that might be causing the issue.
- Save the configuration changes and clear the Magento cache if necessary.
- Test the shipping address form to ensure that the "First Name" field is now displaying correctly.